# Arguments with spaces are seen as separate arguments and not as one argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have the following functions

```
func() { shift 2; func2 $@; }
func2() { echo $1; echo $2; }
func 1 2 "3 3" "4 4"
```

I exepect that `func2` will dispaly `"3 3"` and `"4 4"`. but the func2 see the both 3 as separate args and not as a one arg.

What I m missing here?
how I  can make func2 to see the `"3 3"` as arg1 and `"4 4"` as arg2 ?

Comment: Use quotes: `func2 "$@"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use double quotes around `"$@"` in order for it to work.